# Unable to destroy knockout binding (MetroJS) when navigate to other tabs

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, kendo-ui, gridstack

I am using typescript and Knockout. In my example, I can create tiles and set transactions using kendo custom editor such as fade in fade out or carousel. Based on the timer set for the tile, data will be displayed. However, when I navigate to other tabs, the timer event tries to find tile data which is no longer available, results in throwing an error. I want to ensure when navigated to other tabs, all the tiles having transaction events must be destroyed or unbind. I have tried using  ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () but it never gets called.

```
 init: (element: any, valueAccessor: any, allBindings: any, viewModel: any, bindingContext: any): void => {

        tileState.editableTileInit(element, valueAccessor, viewModel);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            console.log("I have been called");
        });
    },
    update: (element: any, valueAccessor: any, allBindings: any, viewModel: any, bindingContext: any): void => {

        tileState.editableTileUpdate(element, valueAccessor, viewModel);
    }
```

init method will create tiles

```
if (viewModel.editMode() === true) LiveTiles.setupClickHandler(element, viewModel, true);

var sub = viewModel.editMode.subscribe(x => LiveTiles.setupClickHandler(element, viewModel, x));

ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
    sub.dispose();
    TileEditor.destroyEditor(element, viewModel);
    LiveTiles.destroyTile(element, viewModel);
});
```

update method will update the tiles if the user updates the tile at runtime.

```
 TileEditor.destroyEditor(element, viewModel);
    LiveTiles.createTile(element, viewModel);
    if (LiveTiles.shouldRecreateClickHandler(viewModel) === true) {
        LiveTiles.setupClickHandler(element, viewModel, viewModel.editMode());
    }
```

[Tile window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GKsG.png)

[Error when navigated to other tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdXAu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code is needed to be called inside dispose in required .ts file. So whenever user navigate, dispose method will be called and below code will ensure metrojs css will be removed.

```
$('.live-tile')['liveTile']("destroy", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when the user has switched to another tab (in general, out of the window), you can catch the `blur` event on `window`:

```
$(window).blur(() => console.log("window.blur"));
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your response. Problem is I am using MetroJs and when a user changes the route, MetroJs is still attempting to process the data to show transaction on the tile. However, data is not present and it throws a timeout error can be seen in the attached screenshot. I need to make sure when route changes, metro js destroy method should be called.